# Double physical pendulum with constraint

Tags: differential-equations

I am working on double physical pendulum with fixed freedom of one bar. Angle te2 (angle of lower bar) can not be bigger than angle te1 (angle of upper bar) How I can make WhenEvent to get that? Thank you for help.

```
Clear[poincarePend];
m1 = 1; m2 = 1.2; g = 9.81; L1 = 0.5; L2 = 0.6; L = 1.2;
te10 = -6 \[Pi]/12; dte10 = 1.0; te20 = -\[Pi]/2; dte20 = 2.0; tmax = 100; 
steps = 1000000; wd = \[Pi]/12;
poincarePend[m1_, m2_, g_, L1_, L2_, L_, te10_, dte10_, te20_, dte20_,
tmax_, steps_, wd_] :=  temp1 = NDSolve[{dte1[t] - te1'[t] == 0, dte2[t] - 
te2'[t] == 0, ((1/12)*2 L1*2 L1*m1 + m1*L1*L1 + m2*L*L)*dte1'[t] + 
   m2*L2*L*dte2'[t]*Cos[te2[t] - te1[t]] - 
   m2*L*L2*dte2[t]^2*Sin[te2[t] - te1[t]] + 
   g*(m1*L1 + m2*L)*Sin[te1[t]] == 
  0, ((1/12)*2 L2*2 L2*m2 + m2*L2*L2)*dte2'[t] + 
   m2*L1*L*dte1'[t]*Cos[te2[t] - te1[t]] + 
   m2*L*L2*dte1[t]^2*Sin[te2[t] - te1[t]] + g*m2*Sin[te2[t]] == 0,
  dte1[0] == dte10, te1[0] == te10, dte2[0] == dte20, 
 te2[0] == te20, 
 WhenEvent[te2[t] < te1[t], te2[t] -> te1[t]; 
  dte2[t] -> 0 ] }, {te1, dte1, te2, dte2}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
MaxSteps -> steps];
poincarePend[m1, m2, g, L1, L2, L, te10, dte10, te20, dte20, tmax, 
steps, wd];
temp1 = temp1[[1]];
Animate[Graphics[{{PointSize[.01], {Red, 
Point[{x1[t], y1[t]}]}, {Blue, Point[{x2[t], y2[t]}]}, 
Line[{{0, 0}, {x1[t], y1[t]}, {x2[t], y2[t]}}]} /. temp1, {Gray, 
Line[Map[Function[Evaluate[{x2[#], y2[#]} /. temp1]], 
 Range[0, t, 0.02]]]}}, PlotRange -> {{-1.2, 1.2}, {-1.5, .1}}, 
 Axes -> True, Ticks -> False, ImageSize -> 700], {t, 5, 15, .01}, 
 SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

Comment: Coordinates  `{x1[t], y1[t]}, {x2[t], y2[t]}` not defined

Answer (score 2):

Coordinates are not defined. If we remove the excess from the code, correct a couple of typos and add coordinates, then at the output we get

```
m1 = 1; m2 = 1.2; g = 9.81; L1 = 0.5; L2 = 0.6; L = 1.2;
te10 = -6 \[Pi]/12; dte10 = 1.0; te20 = -\[Pi]/
  2; dte20 = 2.0; tmax = 100;
steps = 1000000; wd = \[Pi]/12;
temp1 = NDSolve[{dte1[t] - te1'[t] == 0, 
    dte2[t] - te2'[t] == 
     0, ((1/12)*2 L1*2 L1*m1 + m1*L1*L1 + m2*L*L)*dte1'[t] + 
      m2*L2*L*dte2'[t]*Cos[te2[t] - te1[t]] - 
      m2*L*L2*dte2[t]^2*Sin[te2[t] - te1[t]] + 
      g*(m1*L1 + m2*L)*Sin[te1[t]] == 
     0, ((1/12)*2 L2*2 L2*m2 + m2*L2*L2)*dte2'[t] + 
      m2*L1*L*dte1'[t]*Cos[te2[t] - te1[t]] + 
      m2*L*L2*dte1[t]^2*Sin[te2[t] - te1[t]] + g*m2*Sin[te2[t]] == 0, 
    dte1[0] == dte10, te1[0] == te10, dte2[0] == dte20, 
    te2[0] == te20}, {te1, dte1, te2, dte2}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
   MaxSteps -> steps];
x1[t_] := L1*Sin[te1[t]] /. temp1
y1[t_] := Cos[te1[t]]*L1 /. temp1
x2[t_] := x1[t] + Sin[te2[t]]*L2 /. temp1
y2[t_] := y1[t] + Cos[te2[t]]*L2 /. temp1

{Plot[{x1[t], y1[t]}, {t, 0, 15}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"], 
 Plot[{x2[t], y2[t]}, {t, 0, 15}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]}
```

[image: fig1]

```
ListAnimate[
  Table[Graphics[{{PointSize[.04], Red, 
      Point[-Flatten[{x1[t], y1[t]}]]}, {PointSize[.05], Blue, 
      Point[Flatten[-{x2[t], y2[t]}]]}, {Thick, Orange, 
      Line[{{0, 0}, Flatten[-{x1[t], y1[t]}], 
        Flatten[-{x2[t], y2[t]}]}]}}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-1.2, 1.2}, {-1.2, .6}}, Axes -> True, 
    Ticks -> False, ImageSize -> 300], {t, 0, 15, .05}]]
```

[image: fig2]